# Checking for duplicates in an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have checked for answers on the website, but I am curious about the way I am writing my code via C# to check for duplicates in the array. My function sort of works. But in the end when I print out my 5 sets of arrays, duplicates are detected but, the output still contains duplicates. I have also commented out the part where if a duplicate is detected generate a random number to replace the duplicate found in that element of the array. My logic seems to be sound, a nested for loop that starts with the first element then loop through the same array 5 times to see if the initial element matches. So start at element 0, then loop 5 times to see if 0 through 4 matches element 0, then 1 and so on. Plus generating a random number when a duplicate is found and replacing that element is not working out so good. I did see a solution with using a dictionary object and its key, but I don't want to do that, I want to just use raw code to solve this algorithm, no special objects.

My function:

```
void checkForDuplicates()
    {
        int[] test = { 3,6,8,10,2,3 };
        int count = 0;
        Random ranDuplicateChange; 
        for(int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            count = 0; 
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} :: The current number is: {1} ",i, test[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < test.Length; j++)
            {
               if (test[i] == test[j])
               {
                    count++; 
                    if (count >= 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate found: {0}", test[j]);
                        //ranDuplicateChange = new Random();
                        //test[j] = ranDuplicateChange.Next(1, 72);
                    }
                 }
               }
            }
```

Comment: "No special objects". Hmm, `Console` is quite a special object. Did you ever think about why the second loop starts at `0` and not at `i+1`?

Comment: No speacial object. Just an ordinary HashSet `new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 3, 6, 8, 10, 2, 3 })`

Comment: Are you saying you see to detect duplicates using no "special objects" because this is a homework assignment? Here's some lecture notes that describe sets - http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs2102/common/notes-d13/bsts-and-avls.html -

Comment: No this is not a homework assignment. It looks like Thomas was almost right, it not j = i + 1, it  is j = i which seems to work. But when I try to generate a new random number to the element that has the duplicate, it freaks out. Here is the result.  0 :: The current number is: 3
Duplicate found: 3
 1 :: The current number is: 6
 2 :: The current number is: 8
Duplicate found: 8
 3 :: The current number is: 52
Duplicate found: 52
 4 :: The current number is: 2
 5 :: The current number is: 52

Comment: I am not a student, I program for fun, I like to solve little algorithms. I see things in life and say hmm, I wonder if I can make that in code. This particular project is just to simulate the Lotto game when it issues you random numbers. Per draw. But a constraint in the game is you cannot have duplicates per draw, in the Mega Millions game.

Comment: @NuklearKrisis Then you don't need to check duplicates in array. Create an  array with numbers from 1 to N, [suffle it](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) and take the first m items.

Comment: `But a constraint in the game is you cannot have duplicates per draw, in the Mega Millions game.` Generate random numbers, and add them to a `HashSet` - if `Add` returns `false` (i.e. it was already there) then just generate another one. Then repeat.

Answer (score 2):

You can get them using lambda expressions:

```
var duplicates = test.GroupBy(a => a)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count()});
```

This returns an *IEnumerable* of an anonymous type with 2 properties, *Number* and *Count*

Comment: This works but I think the OP's goal (what's meant by _not using special objects_) is, I believe, is to just manipulate the array and work out an algorithm to achieve the result, not necessarily achieving it by an easy method.

Comment: @Sach ah didn't catch that. I just skimmed through the long paragraph.

Comment: Adiga solution is really fancy. I don't even understand it.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to just use raw code to solve this algorithm, no special objects.

I believe what you mean by this is not using LINQ or any other library methods that are out there that can achieve your end-goal easily, but simply to manipulate the array you have and find a way to find duplicates.

Let's leave code aside for a moment and see what we need to do to find the duplicates. Your approach is to start from the beginning, and compare each element to other elements in the array, and see if they are duplicates. Not a bad idea, so let's see what we need to do to implement that.

Your array:

> test = 3, 6, 8, 10, 2, 3

What we must do is, take 3, see if it's equal to the next element, and then the next, and then the next, until the end of the array. If duplicates are found replace them. 
Second round, take 6, and since we already compared first element 3, we start with 8 and go on till the end of the array. 
Third round, start from 8, and go on.
You get the drift.

Now let's take a look at your code.

Now we start at zero-element (I'm using zero based index for convenience), which is 3, and then in the inner-loop of `j` we see if the next element, 6, is a duplicate. It's not, so we move on. And so on. We do find a duplicate at the last position, then count it. So far so good.

Next loop, now *here* is your first mistake. Your second loop, `j`, starts at `0`, so when `i=1`, the first iteration of your `j` starts at `0`, so you're comparing `test[1] vs test[0]`, which you already compared in the first round (your outer loop). What you *should* instead do is, compare `test[1] vs test[2]`.

So think what you need to change in your code to achieve this, in terms of `i` and `j` in your loops. What you want to do is, start your `j` loop *one more than your current `i` value*.

Next, you increment `count` whenever you find a duplicate, which is fine. But printing the number only when `count >= 2` doesn't make sense. Because, you started it at `0`, and increment only if you found a duplicate, so even if your `counter` is `1`, that means you've found a duplicate. You should instead simply generate a random number and replace `test[j]` with it.

I'm intentionally not giving you code samples as you say that you're eager to learn yourself how to solve this problem, which is always a good thing. Hope the above information is useful.

---

***Disclaimer:***

All the above is simply to show you how to *fix your current code*, but in itself, it still has flaws. To being with, your 'replacing with random number' idea is not watertight. For instance, if it generated the same number you're trying to replace (although the odds are low it *can* happen, and when you write a program you shouldn't rely on chance for your program to not go wrong), you'd still end up with duplicates. Same with if it generated a number that's found at the beginning of the list later on. For example say your list is `2, 3, 5, 3`. The first iteration of `i` would correctly determine `2` is not a duplicate. Then in next iteration, you find that `3` is a duplicate, and replace it. However, there, if the new randomly generated number turned out to be `2`, and since we've already ruled out that `2` is not a duplicate, the newly generated `2` will not be overwritten again and you'll end up with a list with duplicates. To combat that you can revert to your original idea of starting `j` loop with `0` every time, and replace if a duplicate is encountered. To do that, you'll need an extra condition to see if `i == j` and if so skip the inner loop. But even then, the now *newly* generated random number could be equal to one of the numbers in the list to *again* ruining your logic.

So really, it's fine to attempt this problem this way, but you should also compare your random number to your list *every time* you generate a number and if it's equal, then generate *another* random number, and so on until you're good.

But at the end of the day to remove duplicates for a list and replace them with unique numbers there are way more easier and non-error-prone methods using LINQ etc.